# What's the name of this bird species?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

[image]

What's the name of this bird's species, please?

Comment: Welcome. By the looks of it, it's a species of sea eagle. To allow users to effectively ID this specimen, they need some additional information, most notably where (and perhaps when) the picture was taken (country, region, season), and what the approximate size of the animal is.

Comment: http://www.oiseaux-birds.com/article-fish-eagles-feeding-behaviour.html; guessing bald eagle because of habitat (north temperate?) and white restricted to head (not breast ...)

Comment: Is this your picture, or one you found on the web, like [here](https://allpoetry.com/poems/about/collaboration)?  Because it would probably be best to give attribution in the latter case.  Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your post with the location of the picture and an approximate size of the eagle. See [tag:species-identification] for [guidelines](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) for asking ID questions here. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I would say that it is a bald eagle.  I did a search for similar birds but nothing quite matches the build and coloration.  The bird in question appears to be drying out after being in the water.  On the coast of British Columbia they often feed on fish caught from the water's surface and occasionally get a bit damper than they expect, they then have to dry out like the one in your image.  See the following sites: [From Cornell University's site about birds](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Bald_Eagle/species-compare/)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain in more detail why your identification is correct. Specifically, please edit your answer to add discussion of key features that allow you to distinguish this from the several other very similar species of sea eagle. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. ——— You may also wish to take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 

Answer (score -2):

Sure looks like a Golden Eagle to me , white head and tail ( North America).

Comment: Golden eagle with a white head ?  If I saw this in N America I would say it was a bald eagle.

Comment: You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please edit your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. In addition, please address the fact that this looks much more like a species of sea eagle. ——— You may also wish to take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 

Comment: I am absolutely wrong; don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: I may be uninvited from the Christmas bird count which will be in our area Saturday.

Comment: No big deal — we all have "brain farts" (or at least I doubt you and my entire family are the only sufferers). ——— You do know that you can [edit] (or if you don't think this question is worth the extra work delete) your post right?